# About analysing the photo with tesseract

Tags: c#, image-processing

I wrote this code for analyzing the numbers included in picture. It does not give any error while starting but it can not read the numbers. When I start program, it shows an empty `MessageBox`.

I want to read pictures like this:

[image: number image]

The code:

```
private string FotoAnaliz()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\program_goruntusu.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    //string fotopath = @"D:\\program_goruntusu.jpg";
    Bitmap images = new Bitmap(fs);
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng"))
    {
        engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
        // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
        using (var image = new Bitmap(images))
        {
            using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
            {
                using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
                {
                    sayı = page.GetText();
                    MessageBox.Show(sayı);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sayı;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try PSM 10: Treat the image as a single character.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc